# Qt ActiveX dynamicCall: bad parameter count

Tags: c++, qt, activex

I am trying to use an ActiveX control in my program.

```
QAxWidget* mAX = new QAxWidget();
mAX->setControl("{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}");
```

I know that there is a function:

```
put_ChannelType(long newValue)
```

But when I try to execute it:

```
mAX->dynamicCall("put_ChannelType(long)",2);
mAX->dynamicCall("put_ChannelType(int)",2);
mAX->dynamicCall("put_ChannelType(long)",QVariant(2));
mAX->dynamicCall("put_ChannelType(int)",QVariant(2));
```

I get:

```
QAxBase: Error calling IDispatch member put_ChannelType: Bad parameter count
```

Any idea what is going wrong ?

EDIT:

Weird thing is if I call

```
mAX->dynamicCall("put_ChannelType()");
```

I do not get any error message...

EDIT 2:

This also fails (as Constantin suggested)

```
QList<QVariant> varlist;
varlist << (int)1;
mAX->dynamicCall("put_ChannelType(int)",varlist);
```

Comment: I got this error when calling events/slots from different threads incorrectly.  Are you using QThreads?

Comment: no, I am calling this in the QMainWindow constructor

Comment: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/4842 Maybe, pass in a `QList<QVariant> vars` instead?

Comment: yea, I already saw that and tried it too, fail :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this solved using the `generateDocumentation()` function.

I was using this ActiveX control in another application, but an MFC one.

It seems the function names I was referring to (which were in a machine generated IDispatch wrapper class created by VS) were not the same as the ones Qt listed.

i.e. put_ChannelType is actually SetChannelType...

Maybe this is just a version issue ?

Anyways, important part is knowing that `generateDocumentation()` can list you all the functions you can call with `dynamicCall`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it OK?
mAX->dynamicCall("put_ChannelType(const QVariant &)", (long)2);