# Cannot pass arguments to ActiveX COM object using PyQt4

Tags: python, com, pyqt, activex, pyqt4

I'm trying to write some Python code to talk to the Thorlabs APT ActiveX control. I'm basing my code on the code found [on this page](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~krussell/html-pyPL/_modules/APTSystemControl.html), but trying to use PyQt4 ActiveX container instead of the wxPython ActiveX container. It works for a very simple ActiveX methods, however, I get an error when trying to call a method that takes arguments.

This code works and shows the about box for Thorlabs APT:

```
import sys
from ctypes import *

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QAxContainer

class APTSystem(QAxContainer.QAxWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        super(APTSystem, self).__init__()

        self.setControl('{B74DB4BA-8C1E-4570-906E-FF65698D632E}')

        # calling this method works    
        self.AboutBox()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)        
a = APTSystem(app)
```

When I replace `self.AboutBox()` with a method with arguments e.g.:

```
num_units = c_int()
self.GetNumHWUnitsEx(21, byref(num_units))
```

I get an error: `TypeError: unable to convert argument 1 of APTSystem.GetNumHWUnitsEx from 'CArgObject' to 'int&'`

I presume the argument type needs to be a ctypes type. Is there some ctypes magic that can solve this?

Comment: In your reference, I saw wxPython only ?

Comment: Yes, they only used wxPython. I'm trying to avoid that for now, but may not have a choice.

Comment: Or it possibly pyqt and wx pass argument is difference ?  I saw unable to convert argument from 'CArgObject'. Maybe should use 'CArgObject' data-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had the syntax quite wrong, worked it out by using the `generateDocumentation()` function [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14882582/1470749), and some parameter help [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379146/passing-integer-by-reference-in-python). The working code looks like:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QAxContainer
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant

class APTSystem(QAxContainer.QAxWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        super(APTSystem, self).__init__()

        # connect to control
        self.setControl('{B74DB4BA-8C1E-4570-906E-FF65698D632E}')

        # required by device
        self.dynamicCall('StartCtrl()')

        # args must be list of QVariants
        typ = QVariant(6)
        num = QVariant(0)
        args = [typ, num]

        self.dynamicCall('GetNumHWUnits(int, int&)', args)

        # only list items are updated, not the original ints!
        if args[1].toInt()[1]:
            print 'Num of HW units =', args[1].toInt()[0]

        self.dynamicCall('StopCtrl()')

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)        
a = APTSystem(app)
```

The second item in the `args` list contains the correct value, but `num` is never updated by the call.