# PyQt: How to send parameters by reference with QAxWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pass-by-reference, qaxwidget

I'm attempting to use PyQt to talk to an ActiveX COM object in Python. This method works in Python:

```
myobj.dynamicCall('SetAbsMovePos(int, double)', [0, 10])
```

However, I can't send arguments by reference. From the docs, the method I wish to call is:

```
int GetNumHWUnits (int lHWType, int& plNumUnits)
```

and the basic example code is:

```
QVariantList params = ...
int result = object->dynamicCall("GetNumHWUnits(int, int&)", params).toInt();
```

I presume the equivalent code in Python, using ctypes, should be:

```
num = ctypes.c_int()
myobj.dynamicCall('GetNumHWUnits(int, int&)', [6, ctypes.byref(num)])
```

but `num` is never updated.

What's the equivalent code or workaround in Python, and how can I send and later read an argument of type `int&` using Python?

Comment: The code looks correct according to the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference  You know you need to use `num.value` to get the updated value?

Comment: Yes, strictly it should be `num.value`, but that doesn't seem to be the root cause here.

Comment: Looking at the PyQt4 source code (method `dynamicCall()` in `qaxbase.sip`) this is what happens to the arguments, could it be the original references to the objects are lost?

    `QVariant *v = new QVariant(a1->at(i));`
    `PyObject *v_obj = sipConvertFromNewType(v, sipType_QVariant, NULL);`

Comment: Oh, `QVariant` is involed? See my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing an integer by reference in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148496/passing-an-integer-by-reference-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution from the PyQt mailing list. A reference to the list of arguments is needed, as only that list is updated; the original QVariant objects never are. Seems fairly obvious in retrospect!

```
typ = QVariant(6)
num = QVariant(0)
args_list = [typ, num]

self.dynamicCall('GetNumHWUnits(int, int&)', args_list)

print 'Num of HW units =', args_list[1].toInt()[0]
```

A full code example is shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25378588/1470749).

Comment: In PyQt5, the value of a `QVariant` can be obtained from its [`value()` method](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt_qvariant.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could try to pass a list with just one element:

```
def funct(a):
    a[0] = 4

b = [3]
funct(b)
print b[0]
```

Output: 4

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

`QVariant` is involved:

```
    QVariant dynamicCall(const char *, QList<QVariant> & /GetWrapper/);
%MethodCode
        Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
        sipRes = new QVariant(sipCpp->dynamicCall(a0, *a1));
        Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS

        // Update the input list with the (possibly) new values.
        for (SIP_SSIZE_T i = 0; i < PyList_GET_SIZE(a1Wrapper); ++i)
        {
            QVariant *v = new QVariant(a1->at(i));
            PyObject *v_obj = sipConvertFromNewType(v, sipType_QVariant, NULL);
```

In a nutshell, `QVariant` is a wrapper to pass a value by reference.

Which means by passing `c_int`, you have wrapped the value twice. Try to pass a real `QVariant` instead of `c_int` as second argument. Without this, the automatic type coercion in PyQt would take your `c_int`, wrap its value in a `QVariant`, call `dynamicCall`. During the call, the new `QVariant` is updated but there is no connection to the original `c_int` so your instance won't change.

This should work:

```
num = QVariant(0)
myobj.dynamicCall('GetNumHWUnits(int, int&)', [6, num])
print repr(num.value())
```

Comment: That looks a lot better but unfortunately doesn't work. I'm fairly sure the calls order is correct as the equivalent code works in LabVIEW.