# Arguments to PyQT4 QAxWidget work inconsistently

Tags: python, com, pyqt, pyqt4, activex

I'm trying to control a Thorlabs APT ActiveX motor through PyQT4. Here is the simplest version of my initialized class, inspired by code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374622/cannot-pass-arguments-to-activex-com-object-using-pyqt4) and [here](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~krussell/html-pyPL/_modules/APTSystemControl.html).

```
import sys

import comtypes.gen.MG17MotorLib as APTMotorLib

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QAxContainer

channel1 = APTMotorLib.CHAN1_ID

class APTMotor(QAxContainer.QAxWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        super(APTMotor, self).__init__()
        self.setControl('MGMOTOR.MGMotorCtrl.1')
        #motor specific initialization
        self.SetHWSerialNum(my_serial_number)
        self.StartCtrl()
        self.EnableHWChannel(chanel1)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
motor = APTMotor(app)
```

My `motor` object works in many respects. For example, all of the following return the values that I expect.

```
motor.GetStageAxisInfo_MinPos(channel1)
motor.GetStageAxisInfo_MaxPos(channel1)
motor.GetPosition_Position(channel1)
motor.GetStatusBits_Bits(channel1)
```

However, passing arguments into the methods of my `motor` object doesn't quite work properly. For example, consider the method `MoveAbsoluteEx(int lChanID, double fAbsPosCh1, double fAbsPosCh2, bool bWait);`.

I can call `motor.MoveAbsoluteEx(channel1, destination, 0., True)` without error (my motor does not have a channel2). In fact the motor does move. The problem is that, no matter the value of `destination`, my motor always moves to zero mm.

I know from the APT event log that the command being sent actually *is* zero. The relevant output is `CMGMotorCtrl::MoveAbsoluteEx(0,0.0000,0.0000,1)`. The integers are correct (and change when I change the python variables), but the floats are always passed as zero.